# finding the extrapolation from the structure of one data and apply it to the other

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a filter . They are supposed to have the same structure but they are scaled differently and the data from the [top filter](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3HWMYm2lTkVMjBSMldKeUEyUUk/view?usp=sharing) shown in the plot is truncated before 10000. I just set the value equal to zero at 10000 but I would like to extrapolated the top filter in order to follow the structure of the [bottom filter](/vol/aibn84/data4/zahra/photo-z/bpz-1.99.3/FILTER/WFI_I.res). The data related to each filter is provided in the links. I don't know how I can obtain the tail structure from the data in the bottom filter and apply it to the top one considering they have been scaled differently. Note that I need to use the upper panel filter because my other filters are calibrated accordingly.
[image]

I can obtain the interpolation for the lower filter using `interp1d`, but I don't know how I should rescale it properly that can be used for the top filter.

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy import arange
import numpy as np
u=np.loadtxt('WFI_I.res')
f=interp1d(u[:,0], u[:,1])
x=arange(7050, 12000)
y=f(x)
```

I will be grateful for any suggestion or code to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have two filter arrays with y values of `filter1` and `filter2` and x (wavelength) values of `wave1` and `wave2`, then something like this should work (untested though):

```
wave_match = 9500  # wavelength for matching
index1 = np.searchsorted(wave1, wave_match)
index2 = np.searchsorted(wave2, wave_match)
match1 = filter1[index1]
match2 = filter2[index2]
scale = match1 / match2

wave12 = np.concatenate([wave1[:index1], wave2[index2:]])
filter12 = np.concatenate([filter1[:index1], scale * filter2[index2:]])
```

Comment: Thanks very nice answer but there are two points are not  following the structure of top filter. I don't understand why?